# How to create a uint16 numpy array from a uint8 raw image data array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

When interfacing with a USB camera and grabbing image data, I am running into problems with saving the data as 16 bit. I have the camera pixel format set to Mono16, however whenever I save the raw image data to a numpy array, the array defaults to a uint8 datatype. I have noticed that the raw data array doubles in size when switching from Mono8 to Mono16. I have looked into numpy as_strided, but that still didn't fix the issues. Here is a snippet of code to help show a basic example of the situation.

```
>>>c.startCapture()
>>>fireSoftwareTrigger()
>>>im = c.retrieveBuffer()
>>>c.stopCapture()
>>>cols = im.getCols()
>>>cols
964
>>>rows = im.getRows()
>>>rows
724
>>>data = numpy.array(im.getData())
>>>len(data)
1395872
>>>rows*cols
697936
>>>data.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

Comment: Is it defaulting when you save the array or when you create it?  You can check the datatype with `arr.dtype`.

Comment: I edited the post to give a better explanation of the situation. As you can see, the image file size (rows,cols) is half the size of the actual raw data array. The datatype still defaults to uint8.

Comment: And what exactly is the raw data array?

Comment: It seems that the raw data array is being returned as a ndarray with dtype of uint8. Even when the camera Format7 pixel setting is set to Mono16

Comment: You could try view casting `data = numpy.array(im.getData()).view(numpy.uint16)` or if you have to control endianness `'<u2'` or `'>u2'` instead of `numpy.uni16`

Comment: @PaulPanzer That did it! ( .view(numpy.uint16) ) Thank you. I knew there had to be a quick way to convert over without just converting each array value individually. This is my first post so, is there a way I can flag your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: I'll make a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use view casting. Note that view casting reinterprets the data buffer without actually modifying it, so it is cheap.

```
data = numpy.array(im.getData()).view(numpy.uint16)
```

if the data's byte order matches your machine's native one.

Otherwise you'd need to use one of

```
data = numpy.array(im.getData()).view('<u2')
data = numpy.array(im.getData()).view('>u2')
```

the `'>'`/`'<'` in the dtype specification string stands for big/little endian. `'u'` means unsigned int, `'2'` means two bytes.